# How to create a SharePoint 2016 external site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, external-sharing

Is it possible to create an external Sharepoint site on Sharepoint onprem 2016 to share files with users outside of the company?  If so, can someone please point me in the right direction / site where I can find the steps?

Comment: Will users need to login or will this be an anonymous access site?

Comment: If you need external users to login, you can Form Based Authentication (FBA) to handle external users or add external users to your AD. If not, you can enable anonymous access for a site or web application.

Comment: The users will need to log in.  But I'd like to know the steps to follow to create and external site - is there an article or guide somewhere?

Comment: This does not depend on the type of SharePoint site, but on how it is published. You can use any suitable reverse proxy for publishing, or even just open your SP web server's port to the internet through your gateway.